# WP_Query meta_query by array key

Tags: wp-query

I have a custom post type with its meta in an array.  What I need to do is query based on the value of a key in that meta array.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'my-cpt',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',          // Sort by this value
    'meta_key'          => 'my_meta_array',       // Sort by this meta key
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'key here',            // WHAT GOES HERE?
            'value'     => array( 'meta-value' ),
        )
    )
);    

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

What goes in the meta_query key, if my key is my_meta_array[key]?

FYI:
the keys are indexed by my_meta_array[key], stored in the db via update_post_meta( $post_id, 'river_helpers', 'my_meta_array' ), and retrieved via get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_array', true );

Comment: If your value is stored in `$my_meta_array['key']` then ... `$my_meta_array['key']`. That is just a PHP question not a WordPress one.

Comment: Actually it's stored in meta as an array, i.e. $my_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta_array', true );  Then the keys are within the 'my_meta_array' key, i.e. my_meta_array[key] or $my_meta['key'].

Comment: Ok. Got it. That is what you mean. Looks like you already have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. When you save postmeta (or any other meta, for that matter), WordPress runs it through [`maybe_serialize`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize) which turns objects and arrays into [serialized data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). When it gets pulled back out, it is run through [`maybe_unserialize`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize).

Serialized data looks something like this:

```
a:1:{s:3:"one";s:3:"two";}
```

In other words, what get's stored cannot be queried in the way you want. The best you could do is a `LIKE` query, which will be unreliable at best and less performant. Just use `LIKE` [as the `compare` argument of your meta query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Your best bet: rethink how you store meta and move whatever `key` is to its own entry. Meta tables in WordPress are key value stores, it's not unreasonable to store multiple meta values per post type or plugin.